# How to mark a point where object is recognized in Swift

Tags: swift, computer-vision, object-detection, coreml

I'm working on object-recognition project, which is based on YOLO. the problem is once I run

```
   func show(predictions: [YOLO.Prediction]) {
    for i in 0..<boundingBoxes.count {
        if i < predictions.count {
   .
   .
   .
   }
```

to make a bounding box around the object. I don't know how to create a for-loop for making a point at its center once the object is detected on every bounding box, and stay on the screen even an objects is no longer there, and return its coordinate on the screen. any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Since nobody else answered, I'll try to help by giving you a repo link (I'm pretty sure you've already viewed this, but maybe not). https://github.com/hollance/YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph There's an older (iOS10) repo there too using YOLO, along with links to two articles he wrote on them. Hope this gives you a path forward!